# Understanding Leibniz's Formula for $\pi/4$, geometric proof

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

I was reading about Leibniz's geometric proof for $\pi/4$ in this [wiki-page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Leibniz%27s_Formula_for_Pi/Leibniz%27s_Proof). I understand this proof almost completely with the exception of one part where it is stated that:

> $$dC=\bigtriangleup OPQ=\frac{OR\cdot PQ}{2}=\frac{OR\cdot ds}{2}$$

[image]

It wasn't immediately obvious to me **why the two triangles I've drawn have the same area?**

Edit : I've added and edited a figure which illustrates how I'm looking at the two triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Triangles with same base and same height have equal area.

[(proof)](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Triangles_with_Same_Base_and_Same_Height_have_Equal_Area)

[image]

$ds$ is base of the triangle, while $OR$ is altitude from vertex $O$ on extended $PQ$.
[image]

Thus $$ \text{Ar.} \triangle= \frac 12 \times \rm{PQ} \times h =\color{blue}{\frac 12 \times ds \times \rm{OR}} $$

Comment: Thank you for your help @JaideepKhare. I've also updated the figure in my question to illustrate how I'm seeing the problem :) My problem is to see, why the two triangles have equal area.

Comment: @jjepsuomi Any questions left now?

Comment: No, thank you. You're latest picture made it clear. I wasn't aware or had forgotten this geometric fact. No wonder didn't see this :) I thought earlier that the (base $\times$ height) worked only in cases like this: http://mathsrevision26.weebly.com/uploads/1/5/4/9/15493740/6592312.jpg?323

Comment: See Euclid's Bride's Chair Proof [of the Pythagorean Theorem]. He does something very similar. https://twitter.com/johnjoy1966/status/895329760095608833